# How to make Vue Routers Page Transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I can using vue.js with VueRouter. I need to make page transitions but I am not able to. How can I implement this code.

My code is here https://jsbin.com/hopilecona/edit?html,css,js,output

Please help.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I do not know how to add transition code. I need an example.

Comment: Are you talking about transitions described [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)?

Comment: I added my code but it is not working. 

Answer (score 1):

Page transitions work the same as normal transitions, I can see that you have wrapped your router view in the transition, you also want to make sure it's in `out-in` mode, so the first page fades out before the next fades in:

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
```

Now to set up a fade transition you need the following css:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
```

After that it's just a matter of setting up your view router as normal. Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/npe10jot/

Comment: vue.js:990 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <transition> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

This is display my console. It is not working my code :(

Comment: What version of vue are you using?